# Submit Form in DNN, typical answer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

I am trying to submit a mailchimp form from within my DNN (DotNetNuke) site. Typically, you just remove the form tags and put some javascript in the onclick event of the submit button...[like here](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2007/04/03/allowing-html-form-submissions-from-dnn.aspx). This works and you can see as such [here](http://extremeledlightbars.com/Welcome.aspx).

But, I am using this popup module, as I want this form to pop up when someone comes to the site. And in this configuration it does not work. It will submit the form to the designated URL, but **no form data is passed**. This page is [here](http://extremeledlightbars.com/WelcomePopup.aspx).

A couple of observations:

1. When you view the page source, the popup form is within the form tags, yet a this.form returns null in the script.
2. When you inspect the submit button element in Chrome, you see that the html form is then OUTSIDE the form tags.
3. So maybe there is some javascript with this popup module that is moving the DOM element on page load???

I created a js function to call on the input button submit; code is as follows:

```
function submitSubscription(clickedElement){
    $form = $('body').find('form');
    $form.attr('action', 'http://InciteResults.us2.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=6d82b6a028c94cc75005eb4fe&amp;id=1c7ceabac4');
    $form.submit();
}
```

Note: in this function clickedElement.form is returning null.

Comment: Most likely the popup is moving the elements outside of the form. Try placing the form tags inside the popup so that they will move with the inputs.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB, but that doesn't work either. If I do this, and check clickedElement.form, it is null. Then when you click the button, nothing happens and no errors are generated in the console either.

Comment: I can confirm what @KevinB said. The popup is moving the elements outside the form. Inspect with firefox or firebug and you will see. Can you post via ajax or use a different popup that doesn't move elements outside the form such as Bootstrap Modal http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Since the elements aren't rendering inside a form, you can include the original form element in your markup, and not use the JavaScript fallback

Comment: @bdukes yes I tried that too...Actually my configuration, where I enter the HTML for the popup, has the <form> tag in it now, but their code seems to strip form tags in addition to moving the form outside of the original form tags. Not sure why. So looks like I am going to have to "roll my own". Thanks for all the input!

Comment: It looks like the browser doesn't like the `<form>` tag when it initially appears inside the main `<form>`, so it's not in the DOM tree when it's moved to the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your content is not in a `<form>`, you're going to put it inside a `<form>` in order for your script to work.  You can either dynamically create a `<form>` element, or move your content back inside the main `<form>` when you submit.  Try something like this:

```
function submitSubscription(clickedElement){
    var $form = $('<form></form>', { action: 'http://InciteResults.us2.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=6d82b6a028c94cc75005eb4fe&amp;id=1c7ceabac4' });
    $('#mc_embed_signup').wrap($form);
    $form.submit();
}
```